# Vaadin : Converter not working on Vaadin Label

Tags: vaadin

I have a converter which is absolutely working fine for textfield but not working fine for Label.

```
final Label label = new Label("someValue");
label.setContentMode(ContentMode.TEXT);
label.setConverter(new DataConverter());
```

DataConverter() is having the logic for convertToPresentation(), but it's not being called at all when label is rendered onto the grid.

The same is working fine for the TextField.

```
final TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.setConverter(new DataConverter());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show `DataConverter` implementation? It's hard to tell anything without it

Comment: Also, why do you not have `convertToModel()` implemented? It is used internally to test that the converter works fine.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have rewritten the entire logic and not having any issues now.